# Where is the "python" environment variable set?

Tags: python, npm-install, gyp

I have run into an issue with installing some npm packages for an app on Windows 10. Specifically gyp seems to be causing trouble, because it cannot find the python executable.

Here is part of the output of `npm install` in PowerShell:

[image]

Previously I had Cygwin installed, but then I deleted it, updated to Windows 10 and installed the Linux Subsystem for Windows. But obviously the Cygwin python path is still somewhere set in an environment variable.

The problem is, I cannot find this environment variable.

The `python` environment variable is set to `C:\Users\myaccount\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe`.

The `path` environment variable only contains `C:\Users\myaccount\.windows-build-tools\python27\`, no other python directories.

There is no `pythonpath` environment variable.

I checked all these variables with PowerShell and in Extended System Settings.

Where on earth is npm or gyp taking the python path from?

Comment: Try removing the environment variable `python` and making one called `PYTHON` (all uppercase).

Comment: @L3viathan Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately this did not change anything.

Comment: Also, restarting the system did not help.

Comment: Tried uninstalling, then reinstalling Python?

Comment: I found it! It was in the npm config file. Calling `npm config delete python` solved everything.

Comment: @L3viathan Yes, I guess several times. Problems were even worse under Windows 7 with Cygwin. Thanks for feedback, issue is solved now (see other comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, before looking at the environment variables `gyp` looks in [npm-config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) for a `python` entry. In my case the `python` entry was set like this:

```
; userconfig C:\Users\myaccount\.npmrc
python = "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\python2.7.exe"
```

After deleting the `python` entry in npm-config with

```
npm config delete python
```

`gyp` found the python executable trough the `python` environment variable.